# xCode Increment reset to 0

Tags: c#, ios, xcode

I'm new to xCode I'm having a Button that Increment the Value of a Label by 1 on every Tap, I have Another Button that should Reset the Value of the Label to 0, the increment works perfect and the Reset is is doing the job and Changing the Value to 0.

My Problem is: when you Click the Increment Button it will start where you stopped, e.g. you stopped the counter at 49 then reset to 0! Clicking the Increment button will go to 50 etc...

P.S. I'm new to Coding!

Here is my Code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
    count++;

    scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", count];
}
- (IBAction)resetButton {
    scoreLabel.text = @"0";

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
    count++;
    scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", count];
}
- (IBAction)resetButton {
    count = 0; //Resets the count
    scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", count];;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that in your `-resetButton` method you don't resetting value of your count, you're just setting text to your label.

ArthurMe is right. But you get some basic understanding of programming, here's good sites,books to help you with that:

Books for start

- Programming in Objective-C 2.0 by Stephen G. Kochan
- Beginning iPhone development by Dave Mark & Jeff LaMarche

Good sites with tutorials

- [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials)

Try to finish and understand this cool project - http://csedweek.org

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at it :)